# Polynomial ring as a ring of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

My book describes the polynomial ring $R[X]$ as: $R[X] = R[\mathbb{N}] = \{f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow R | \hspace{ 2mm} f(n) = 0, n \gg 0\}$. What is exactly meant by this?

What do the double arrows mean $(\gg)$? The author is a Danish mathematician and the book is designed for a first semester algebra course.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: I'm sorry about the title. I'll try to be more direct next time. For this question, I didn't want put too tex

Answer (score 2):

The $>>0$ just means for all sufficiently large natural numbers.
Now how to swallow this confusing definition. Intuitively a polynomial in $R[x]$ is just $a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_n^n$ for some $a_0,a_1,...,a_n \in R$. Of course, this is not a very rigorous definition. So let's analyze this definition. First of all, $f(n)$ is supposed to represent the coefficient on $x^n$ (or maybe $x^{n-1}$ depending on what the convention for $\mathbb{N}$ is in Denmark). So our polynomial is just $P(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n)x^n$.

The $f(n) = 0, n >> 0$ just means for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $f(n) = 0$. This is to guarantee the polynomial has a bounded degree. So this is basically how this definition works. Its essentially defining the polynomial as a sequence of its coefficients, where for all sufficiently large indices we have the element equals $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\gg$ usually means "far greater", which in most contexts is not a precise statement. In this, it means $\exists N\in\mathbb{N} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\colon f(n)=0$ or "$f$ eventually vanishes" or, equivalently, "$f$ is non-zero for only finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$"

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineering this cryptic piece of notation, I would guess that since what *should* be intended is that $f$ is $0$ at all but finitely many values, the $\gt\gt$ is actually meant to be $\gg$ (produced by the $\TeX$ command `\gg`), a symbol that usually means "far greater than" and is being used in an unusual way here, not least since it usually means that the *ratio* of the quantities is large, whereas there is no ratio in comparison to $0$, so if the symbol was going to be used at all, it should have been $n\gg1$.

Answer (score 0):

The author appears to be constructing the polynomial ring as a special case of a [monoid ring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) See the linked Wikipedia page for details.